# Consolidate iOS Share Extension related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

### Issue

Currently multiple tags exist related to the iOS Share Extension:

1. [ios8-share-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios8-share-extension)
2. [share-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/share-extension)

Tag #1 is outdated because the share extension was introduced in iOS 8 but tag has been used for any iOS version really.

Tag #2 seems too generic because it is not specifically referring to iOS which can lead to wrong use of tag.

### Proposed solution

Consolidate both tags into a new tag [ios-share-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-share-extension).

Comment: Maybe before this is done you might want to clean-up [tag:share-extension] by retagging any questions that have nothing to do with iOS.

Comment: Would there be any objection for a rename and a synonym?

Comment: @rene You mean renaming `ios8-share-extension` to `ios-share-extension` and making `share-extension` a synonym for it? (sorry, I'm not too familiar with the concept of synonyms for tags)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I suggest. New tags first need to be added to a question with an edit. You can't create tags out of thin-air, not even mods can.

Comment: @rene I can add the new tag to a question I just posted, hence I stumbled upon the issue, if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what is more convenient for a mod. It doesn't look like much mods are active now, or at least the ones I dare to ping so we have to wait a bit.

Comment: I think renaming `ios8-share-extension` to `ios-share-extension` makes more sense, because the tag has been used for years now for any iOS version (iOS 9 was released in 2015)